# AWS Lambda SQS sendMessage sometimes does not returns response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Well, It works in most cases, but sometimes msg is lost, there is no response from sendMessage, no success or failure, here is some code snippet:

```
try {
const value = await sqs
  .sendMessage({
    QueueUrl: URL,
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(msg),
    MessageAttributes: {
      type: {
        StringValue: 'doJob',
        DataType: 'String'
      }
    }
  })
  .promise();
logger.info('doJob success');
} catch (e) {
  logger.error('error in doJob: ');
}
```

Does anyone had the same issue before? any ideas why it is happening or how to fix it?

note: I'm using AWS-SDK on nodejs

Comment: Just to clarify: neither "doJob success" or "error in doJob:" gets printed? So the sqs calls hangs forever?
Are you running it from a lambda? Is it possible the function times out before the sqs send returns?

Comment: @Tamas nope, non of them were printed, yes from a lambda, no timeout.
I find it out already, it was a silly mistake, can't even imagine... there was missing await when invoking function and that was the reason.

(existing code so hard to see the problem)
Thanks fo your time!